# IntelliJ not able to find spock package after clearing grails ivy cache

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-idea, spock

Here's what happened today:

I am still learning my way around grails, so I screwed something up in the config.groovy file without realizing it, which broke my grails. It could no longer find the right version of Spock. Without realizing what the problem was, I tried several things, including `rm -rf ~/.grails/ivy-cache`. I found my mistake eventually, and can now run grails test-app just fine from the command line. However, IntelliJ can't find spock anymore, so the convenience of being able to run the test from its interface is gone.

The specific problem I'm having is that IntelliJ gives me a `Cannot resolve symbol 'spock'`. The only difference I have noticed between now and before is that under External Libraries in the project view, there used to be libraries downloaded by grails with lists of plugins. Now, there is nothing.

I've tried reinstalling my Spock plugin. I've shied away from independently downloading the spock jar, because if it's even slightly different from the one my build machine is using, the chances I'll check in broken files is high.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I imagine you have already done, but just in case, File > Invalidate Caches / Restart.

Comment: I hadn't done that, but it didn't end up working anyhow. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake, how I fixed the issue:

I deleted my git repo, re-downloaded it, and created a new intellij project from the source. Extreme, and unpleasant, but I got my code working again.